# How to access the generated File by jenkins server through URL?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am using jenkins. 
In Each build I execute from Jenkins I am storing a build number in a Test file called Build.txt
Which is in opt/jenkins/  path.

I want to access this file through an URL from a browser.

Is it possible and How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you generate this file in the job workspace?

Answer (score 0):

you can artifact the build files using

Post build -> Archieve artifacts

you can see those archieved files in URL using below plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Archived+Artifact+Url+Viewer+PlugIn

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use Jenkins [userContent](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/User+Content) directory. Jenkins has a mechanism known as "**User Content**", where administrators can place files inside **$JENKINS_HOME/userContent,** and these files are served from http://yourhost/jenkins/userContent.

1. Make sure your jenkins have [Copy To Slave Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) installed.
2. In your job config page, **Add Post-build Action-->Copy files back to the job's workspace on the master node**.
   [image]
3. In the **Files to copy** field, fill in the files that you want to copy from the slave node back to the jenkins master's corresponding workspace of current job.
   [image]
4. Goto your **$JENKINS_HOME/userContent** folder, create a link to  **$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/yourjob/workspace/screenshot** by issuing command for example:

   > ln -s screenshot /home/ci/jenkins/jobs/tc_ui_test/workspace/screenshot/
5. After that, you can access your contents from url: http://yourhost/jenkins/userContent/screenshot